# Function returns before its finished

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets

I'm trying to implement a socket connection between a python server and a flutter client,

everything works well, but when I want to get the response back the function returns null and then prints the response.

I'm receiving the response but after the function returns.

```
String  rcev_response()  {
    String response = "";
    
    socket.listen((event) {
      response = utf8.decode(event);
      print(response);
     });
  
    return response;
  }
```

Any idea what's happening here and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
After a little bit of debugging, I found out that socket.listen() doesn't actually stop. so the function returns the value before its assigned

and I added a 1ms delay before the return and now it's working properly.

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), onceAtTheEndOfTheBatch);
```

this is still not a solution. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to add async

```
Future<String>  rcev_response() async {
   String response = "";

   await socket.listen((event) {
     response = utf8.decode(event);
     print(response);
   });

return response;}
```

maybe this help you :)

Comment: tried it already, it didn't work.

Comment: I am sorry idk what is the solution

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous function that you are passing to listen is going to be called multiple times with chunks of the response. It's up to you to concatenate them. As you need a string you can use the stream join convenience function.

```
Future<String> rcev_response() async {
  Socket s = await Socket.connect(ipAddr, port);
  s.add(utf8.encode(request));
  String result = await utf8.decoder.bind(s).join();
  await s.close(); // probably need to close the socket
  return result;
}
```

This assumes that the server will close the socket when it's finished sending.

Comment: it gives an error "The argument type 'Utf8Decoder' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>'."

Comment: sorry the code is updated in the newest flutter version, already updated the answer

Comment: it did partially work, but I want to keep the connection alive.
is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

## **A solution but still not optimal.**

I found out that it works properly if I close the socket from the server side and re-initialize it every time I send a request from the client side.

For example - Server side process:

```
# accept connection 
client_socket, client_address = self.server_socket.accept()

# receive the message 
client_socket.recv()

# send response 
client_socket.send()

# close socket 
client_socket.close()
```

But I still want to keep the connection alive as a full duplex connection, if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you still not solved this.

```
String  rcev_response() async {
    
    var completer = Completer<String>();
    socket.listen((event) {
      String response = "";
      response = utf8.decode(event);
      print(response);
      if (!completer.isCompleted) {
       completer.complete(response);
      }
     });
  
    return await completer.future;
  }
```

This will return the first event received by the socket as method return value... and socket will still be listening and printing other received events.
Hope it helps.